# How to interpret 節はありません

Tags: meaning, interpretation

Context:
from ep 3 of Death Note L suspects Kira might 
be a student, based on the time of death of the 
victims, so Kira starts killing criminals each 
one every hour so as to prove that he is not a 
student.

This is from a blog:

> キラがすぐにこのような「１時間置きの連続殺人」を実行しているこ
>   とから、やはり当初の『キラが学生である』との推測が当たっていると判断す
>   るのが自然なのですが、
>   なぜか現時点ではＬはそのように考えている節はありませんでしたね
>   。もっとも、あらゆる固定概念を捨て去るべきであるとＬ自身も言って
>   いましたから、今回の事件だけでは彼は断定しないのでしょうけど。

To me this paragraph means:

> From the fact that Kira is killing criminals 
>   every hour  guessing that "kira is a student" 
>   is still natural but, **somehow it's not 
>   unusual L thinks like that(?)**(なぜか現時点ではＬ
>   はそのように考えている節はありませんでしたね。(That's the 
>   sentence I can't understand))

And I don't know how is that related to this 
part:

> もっとも、あらゆる固定概念を捨て去るべきであるとＬ自身も言って
>   いましたから、今回の事件だけでは彼は断定しないのでしょうけど。
>   At most(?), because L said that we should get 
>   rid of all preconceived thoughts/ stereotypes, 
>   L didn't arrive at a conclusion as for the 
>   present case(?)

Is the author criticizing L in this paragraph or just stating some incongruencies?

Comment: "It did not appear to me that L was thinking like that at this point."